# Compare Python Dictionary values with Django Database fields

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for a way to compare a python dictionary values with Django ORM entries. I have a dictionary contains product information like following:

```
products = {
    "552049": {
        "ProductId": "552049",
        "BarCode": "552049",
        "Height": 200,
        "WholesalePrice": 10.65,
        "RetailPrice": 12.78,
        "Length": 62,
        "LongDescription": "Spray 400ml",
        "ShortDescription": "",
        "Volume": 818,
        "Weight": 354,
        "Width": 66,
    },
    "552050": {
        "ProductId": "552050",
        "BarCode": "552050",
        "Height": 200,
        "WholesalePrice": 10.65,
        "RetailPrice": 12.78,
        "Length": 62,
        "LongDescription": "Spray 400ml",
        "ShortDescription": "",
        "Volume": 818,
        "Weight": 354,
        "Width": 66,
    },
}
```

These values stored on a Django database. The number of products are very big, about 200.000 products and after a few days I need to compare and update the products if something change. I know that a way is to iterate to products and compare values but I'm looking for a better approach to compare products more faster.

I'm thinking about to create a checksum and stored as a field in database and later when I update the products, first compare the checksum and if is different then update the database field. But I don't know if this the best way.

Can someone suggest me a fast way for this?

EDIT 1

Here is a preview of product model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    added_at = models.DateTimeField('Added DateTime', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Update DateTime', auto_now=True)
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    old_productid = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    supplier_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    commodity_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    brand_label = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    category_label = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    description_1 = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    description_2 = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    description_3 = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    short_description_1 = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    short_description_2 = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    short_description_3 = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    further_description = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    width = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    length = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    volume = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    weight = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Compare these *how*? If you just want to inject the new values for a product with the given `ProductId`, that is indeed easy to do.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I know how to iterate to products, compare values and update the values that been changed. I looking for a fast way to check for changes (without check every value) and update the values if changed. that's why I'm thinking of using something like checksum

Comment: I don't think a checksum is needed: checksums can accidently match, and furthermore will have approximately the same amount of work performance-wise. But is `ProductId` the "primary key" of your model? Can you show the model you aim to update?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The "primary key" of model is the auto-created "id". I edit my post to include a "short" version of model because there is many fields

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem my thought was to create a checksum for the dictionary with the following `checksum = hashlib.md5(json.dumps(product_1).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()` and store checksum value to a new field of Product model. The next time I need to check for changes, I create again the checksum of dictionary and compare it with stored checksum. If is different, then iterate to dict values and update product. I don't know if this is a proper way

Comment: but this thus maps to the `id`, the `ProductId`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edit the dictionary to make more clearly what I have to do. I read the products (about 200.000) and create a dict with `ProductId` as a key and all product info as a dict. i choose this instead list of dicts for more speed. Then for every product I get it from db with `object.filter(product_code='dict_key')` and compare the checksum as describe

Answer (score 0):

It is likely counterproductive to work with checksums: the same checksum does *not* guarantee that the two items are the same, hashes like md5 are known to be *insecure*: one can effectively change two values to produce the same checksum, for two different items.

```
mapping = {
    'BarCode': 'barcode',
    'Height': 'height',
    # 'WholesalePrice': '???',
    # 'RetailPrice': '???',
    'Length': 'length',
    'LongDescription': 'description_1',
    'ShortDescription': 'short_description_1',
    'Volume': 'volume',
    'Weight': 'height',
    'Width': 'width',
}

seen = set()
to_update = []
for prod in Product.objects.filter(product_code__in=products).iterator():
    seen.add(prod.product_code)
    prod_data = products[prod.product_code]
    for k, v in mapping.items():
        setattr(prod, v, prod_data[k])
    to_update.append(prod)
    if len(to_update) > 10_000:
        Product.objects.bulk_update(to_update, fields=list(mapping.values()))
        to_update = []
if to_update:
    Product.objects.bulk_update(to_update, fields=list(mapping.values()))

Product.objects.bulk_create(
    [
        Product(**{v: product[k] for k, v in mapping.items()}, product_code=pid)
        for pid, product in products.items()
        if pid not in seen
    ]
)
```

This will work in (large) batches that will both edit and create new `Product`s for items missing in the database. The `mapping` is a dictionary that specifies how the items in the dictionary map to the model objects counterparts.

The important part is to prevent making queries *per* `Product`: we here create and update items in bulk, so a large number of `Product`s all in the *same* query.

Checksums are usually used to correct errors in data, like an invalid barcode, or for security reasons, for example a hash as a way to have *some* guarantee that this is the same file you signed.

But checksums can only work in one way: if the checksum of two things is different, we know the two things are different. It does *not* work the other way around: two things with the same checksum do *not* guarantee the same value. While for cryptographic hashes the *aim* is to indeed do this, one can never fingerprint an arbitrary amount of data in a fixed-sized bytestream and thus guarantee that the data is the same.

But even if the checksums would somehow be able to do that, it would introduce a new column, preferably with an index, that thus then will be queried.